# calling command button from another command button

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a macro that calls from another command button to run a SQL query. When I run the code i keep getting an error message that says `run time error 1004. Macro's may not be available in this workbook or may not be enabled.` I checked to see if macros are enabled and they are enabled on all sheets. I am using the `application.run` method to do this. Any other reason besides the fact the macros are not enabled?

Here is the line of code I am using.

```
Application.Run "'CostBreakDownbyWorkOrder-Query.xlsm'!btnRunReport_Click"
```

Comment: Is the Sub you're tring to call flagged as `Public`? Is it in a regular module, or in a worksheet module?

Comment: The sub is marked Public and they are regular modules

Comment: Are you trying to call an event handler? Wouldn't it be easier to put the `btnRunReport_Click` code in its own sub routine and call it from both the click event and this macro?

Comment: Just to be clear, both the button and the macro are in CostBreakDownbyWorkOrder-Query.xlsm?  And we're talking about an ActiveX button on a WorkSheet and not one on a UserForm? And btnRunReport works when you click it?

Comment: Would that work even if they are called from seperate workbooks @Bmo?

@Comintern They are both ActiveX buttons and they are located in separate workbooks. btRunReport works when clicked on the original workbook.